# Color Pygame integer?

Tags: python, colors, integer, pygame, gradient

Hi I'm trying to make a black an white gradient in Pygame it works just fine, from the start of surface to the end, but when I try to start after some pixels

```
from pygame import gfxdraw 

surf = pygame.Surface([256,16], pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)

screen.blit(surf,(0,0))

for y in range(0,16,1):
    for x in range(0,256,1):
        colPos = [0.25,1]
        rG = int(1/(colPos[1]-colPos[0])*x)
        gG = int(1/(colPos[1]-colPos[0])*x)
        bG = int(1/(colPos[1]-colPos[0])*x)
        gfxdraw.pixel(surf, x, y, (rG,gG,bG,255))
```

but it show me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\game.py", line 76, in <module>
gfxdraw.pixel(surf4, x, y, (rG,gG,bG,255))
TypeError: invalid color argument
```

I mean it is a integer, why does the error show up?

Answer (score 1):

Because for values of `x` greater than or equal to `192`, the result of `int(1/(colPos[1]-colPos[0])*x)` is larger than `255`, and therefore not a valid argument.

```
>>> for x in range(190, 195):
    print x, int(x / 0.75) # I simplified the equation


190 253
191 254
192 256
193 257
194 258
```